# Need to clone repository after SSH into server using TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a job that SSH into server and after that I need to git clone repository into this server that I SSHed before. How could I do it?
I set VCS checkout mode on agent, and set custom path

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to achieve it:

1. Use SSH Exec runner to execute git clone on remote machine
2. Use SSH Upload to upload previously cloned repository to remote machine

First one is faster but you need to take care of git auth on remote machine.